Improving performance when adding multiple UserControls to a FlowLayoutPanel
I'm working on a WinForms application where I need to dynamically add a large number of UserControl items to a FlowLayoutPanel. The current approach works but suffers from noticeable performance issues, especially when adding a large number of controls at once.
Here's a simplified code I'm using:
flowLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout();

foreach (var item in items) 
{
    var userControl = new MyUserControl();
    flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(userControl);
}

flowLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout();

I need to add 5 flowLayoutPanel finally to my Panel where every flowLayoutPanel have ~10 UserControls.
Single UserControl isn't advanced, its just a panel with 4 text boxes, label, na 2 panels:

What I've tried:

using SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout around the loop.
setting Visible = false before adding controls and then setting Visible = true after.
double buffering the FlowLayoutPanel.

None of these attempts have significantly improved performance.

When you have such problems, your performance issue could stem form two different possible sources: either you have a slow logic that is slowing the process down, or the graphical display is slow. So, first do some measurements and identify which line is slow:

flowLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout()
var userControl = new MyUserControl()
flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(userControl)
flowLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout()

Note that the second and the third are repeated actions, you do best to repeat measuring their time usage inside the loop and calculate the sum of it.
If your logic related to MyUserControl is slow, then you will need to optimize it. If adding it is slow, then you have a graphical problem and it would make sense to set IsVisible to false for your newly created userControl before you add it. If suspending or resuming the layout is slow, then you have a graphical issue.
Anyways, you will need to perform the research described above, there are chances that it will solve your problem. Repeatedly rerendering graphics is slow, so you need to detect whether it happens. It is also possible that it happens but due to some other reason.

I created a List and added all the controls to the list. Then, I used flowLayoutPanel.Controls.AddRange(myList.ToArray()) to add them to the FlowLayoutPanel. Even with SuspendLayout, each AddRange operation (because I have multiple FlowLayoutPanel instances) can take up to 500ms. I discovered that the main performance issue is caused by the 4 TextBox controls placed on each MyUserControl. Is there any way to improve performance? I need to have four input fields where the user can enter values for each UserControl.

Where are you adding the four textboxes? That part of the code is not shown in your question.

TextBoxes are part of my design of MyUserControl. Single FlowLayoutPanel can contain 20 MyUserControl which have 4 textboxes each.
